# Select from 5 Tables and show Results

Tags: sql, codeigniter

1. Table: Teacher

```
ID_Teacher   Password   Id_Users  Name
--------------------------------------
1001         1234          1       A
1002         1234          2       B
```

2. Table: Student

```
Id_Student   Password   Id_Users  Name
--------------------------------------
52001         1234          3       C
52002         1234          4       D
```

3. Table: Employee

```
Id_Employee   Password   Id_Users  Name  Country
--------------------------------------------------
60001         1234          5       E   NewYork
60002         1234          6       F   London
```

4. Table: Shop

```
Id_Shop   Password   Id_Users    Name  Country
--------------------------------------------------
70001         1234          7       G   NewYork
70002         1234          8       H   London
```

5. Table:Transaction

```
ID_Transaction   Transaction_Of(Fk Id_Users)   Method    Recived_Transaction(Fk Id_Users)  Money   Status    TimeStamp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                          1                     Tranfer       5                           500     Sucess  2020-01-05 18:00:00
2                          5                     Tranfer       8                           500     Sucess  2020-01-05 18:00:00
```

I need this

Result:

```
ID_Transaction   Transaction_Of   Method    Recived_Transaction(Fk Id_Users)  Money   Status    TimeStamp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                          A      Tranfer       E               500     Sucess  2020-01-05 18:00:00
2                          E      Tranfer       H               500     Sucess  2020-01-05 18:00:00
```

How I can write query?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I've removed your conflicting RDBMS tags - please add back the correct one.

Comment: I assume you `ID_Users` column is unique across all 4 tables? From your transaction table do you have anyway to know which other table it applies to?

Comment: i use MySQL sir

Comment: use `join query`

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
$result = $this->db->select("t.ID_Transaction, c.Name, t.Method, e.Name, t.Money, t.Status, t.TimeStamp")
           ->join("Teacher as c" , "t.Transaction_Of = c.Id_Users")
           ->join("Employee as e" , "t.Recived_Transaction = e.Id_Users")
           ->get("Table_Transaction as t")->result_array();
```